# Script score function must not produce negative scores / Query Failed / All shards failed for phase query elasticsearch

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch

I have an asp.net core 3.1 web api, that indexes documents to elasticsearch and queries the data via a frontend input field. It works. But after a period of time, when I try to search for documents that had already been indexed, let's say 5 hours ago, it doesn't give me any results and gives me the following errors:

```
- all shards failed for phase query elasticsearch
- `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: script score function must not produce negative scores, but got: [-1010.1054077148438]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [CVSearcher-ElasticSearch][10.0.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: script score function must not produce negative scores, but got: [-2020.2108154296875]
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException$1: script score function must not produce negative scores, but got: [-2020.2108154296875]
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.guessRootCauses(ElasticsearchException.java:644) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:59) [elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$ConnectionCountingHandler.handleException(SearchTransportService.java:423) [elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1118) [elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1227) [elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
```

Why is this happening?

My scoring scripts look like this:

```
        public IEnumerable<Func<ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<ResumeDocument>, ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<ResumeDocument>>> ScoringScripts
    {
        get
        {
            //build a list of every scoring script.
            var scriptCollection = new List<Func<ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<ResumeDocument>, ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<ResumeDocument>>>();

            //add the location scoring function once geocoding is incorporated in the application
            //scriptCollection.Add(LocationScoringFunction);

            //Iterate over every technicalskill requirement in the filters, and add a corresponding script for this technical skill.
            foreach (var skill in _filters.TechnicalSkills)
            {
                scriptCollection.Add(sc => sc
                    .ScriptScore(fq => fq
                        //Add a filter so the script only applies to this specific technical skill
                        .Filter(fi => fi
                            .Term(t => t
                                .Field(ff => ff.TechnicalSkills.First().Id)
                                .Value(skill.TechnicalSkillId)
                            )
                        )
                        //Add the script itself. More details for building a scoring script can be found at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html
                        .Script(s => s
                        .Source("(doc['technicalSkills.yearsOfExperience'].value/params.minYears) + (doc['technicalSkills.interest'].value / 20) + (doc['technicalSkills.level'].value/20)")
                        .Params(p =>
                                p.Add("minYears", skill.MinYears + 1)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );
            }

            return scriptCollection;
        }
    }
```

I added this code to see more information:

```
var debugInformation = response.DebugInformation;
```

Results:

```
"Valid NEST response built from a successful (200) low level call on POST: /resumes/_search?typed_keys=true\n# Audit trail of this API call:\n - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://elastic:9200/ Took: 00:00:01.0811937\n# Request:\n{}\n# Response:\n{\"took\":0,\"timed_out\":false,\"_shards\":{\"total\":1,\"successful\":1,\"skipped\":0,\"failed\":0},\"hits\":{\"total\":{\"value\":1,\"relation\":\"eq\"},\"max_score\":1.0,\"hits\":[{\"_index\":\"resumes\",\"_type\":\"_doc\",\"_id\":\"b10ca54d-e90f-428e-8edd-cca7f168bd27\",\"_score\":1.0,\"_source\":{\"id\":\"b10ca54d-e90f-428e-8edd-cca7f168bd27\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"2020-12-30T12:00:00.2240000Z\",\"firstname\":\"Murat\",\"surname\":\"Yilmaz\",\"gender\":\"Man\",\"nationality\":\"dasdfds\",\"description\":\"wef\",\"location\":{\"lat\":0.0,\"lon\":0.0},\"trainings\":[],\"languageSkills\":[],\"technicalSkills\":[{\"id\":\"8004b47f67a94ccf92e6054a\",\"name\":\"React\",\"interest\":0,\"level\":0,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2019.8740588637916},{\"id\":\"0133a6138f5d47a3a84df694\",\"name\":\"Typescript\",\"interest\":0,\"level\":0,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2019.8740588637916},{\"id\":\"e715dc3a4da34cd29a4adec0\",\"name\":\"Javascript\",\"interest\":0,\"level\":0,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2019.8740588637916},{\"id\":\"0c2a67d0f6e2431c81dc211f\",\"name\":\"Programmeertalen\",\"interest\":1,\"level\":1,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2023.1211498973305},{\"id\":\"5ecfbfd816e79f6308ffa522\",\"name\":\"Technische skills\",\"interest\":1,\"level\":1,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2023.1211498973305},{\"id\":\"03c972e8f0404eba9087d77a\",\"name\":\"C#\",\"interest\":0,\"level\":0,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2.9158110882956882},{\"id\":\"0c2a67d0f6e2431c81dc211f\",\"name\":\"Programmeertalen\",\"interest\":1,\"level\":1,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2023.1211498973305},{\"id\":\"5ecfbfd816e79f6308ffa522\",\"name\":\"Technische skills\",\"interest\":1,\"level\":1,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2023.1211498973305},{\"id\":\"8fd0bb8e1eb24ef697f7a191\",\"name\":\"Java\",\"interest\":0,\"level\":0,\"yearsOfExperience\":-0.33127994524298426},{\"id\":\"0c2a67d0f6e2431c81dc211f\",\"name\":\"Programmeertalen\",\"interest\":1,\"level\":1,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2023.1211498973305},{\"id\":\"5ecfbfd816e79f6308ffa522\",\"name\":\"Technische skills\",\"interest\":1,\"level\":1,\"yearsOfExperience\":-2023.1211498973305}]}}]}}\n"
```

Some more logs:

```
[2020-11-05T01:30:00,000][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MlDailyMaintenanceService] [CVSearcher-ElasticSearch] triggering scheduled [ML] maintenance tasks
[2020-11-05T01:30:00,038][INFO][o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction] [CVSearcher-ElasticSearch] Deleting expired data
[2020-11-05T01:30:00,051][INFO ][o.e.x.s.SnapshotRetentionTask] [CVSearcher-ElasticSearch] starting SLM retention snapshot cleanup task
[2020-11-05T01:30:00,054][INFO ][o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction] [CVSearcher-ElasticSearch] Completed deletion of expired ML data
[2020-11-05T01:30:00,054][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MlDailyMaintenanceService] [CVSearcher-ElasticSearch] Successfully completed [ML] maintenance tasks
[2020-11-05T15:26:06,117][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction] [CVSearcher-ElasticSearch] [resumes][0], node[E1-wByZ3SkaTJ7BK0TvIoQ], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=hg3RohUHQx6UynW2I2ghmA]: Failed to execute [SearchRequest{searchType=QUERY_THEN_FETCH, indices=[resumes], indicesOptions=IndicesOptions[ignore_unavailable=false, allow_no_indices=true, expand_wildcards_open=true, expand_wildcards_closed=false, allow_aliases_to_multiple_indices=true, forbid_closed_indices=true, ignore_aliases=false, ignore_throttled=true], types=[], routing='null', preference='null', requestCache=null, scroll=null, maxConcurrentShardRequests=0, batchedReduceSize=512, preFilterShardSize=128, allowPartialSearchResults=true, localClusterAlias=null, getOrCreateAbsoluteStartMillis=-1, ccsMinimizeRoundtrips=true, source={"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"match_all":{"boost":1.0}},"functions":[{"filter":{"term":{"technicalSkills.id":{"value":"0c2a67d0f6e2431c81dc211f","boost":1.0}}},"script_score":{"script":{"source":"(doc['technicalSkills.yearsOfExperience'].value/params.minYears) + (doc['technicalSkills.interest'].value / 20) + (doc['technicalSkills.level'].value/20)","lang":"painless","params":{"minYears":1}}}}],"score_mode":"multiply","boost_mode":"sum","max_boost":3.4028235E38,"boost":1.0}}}}]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [CVSearcher-ElasticSearch][10.0.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.executeInternal(QueryPhase.j
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add your query to the question as well? specially your function score. Thanks!

Comment: Hi saeednasehi. I have included the code. I hope it is understandable enough..

Comment: The only way to get a negative score with your script is if any document contains a negative value for either `yearsOfExperience` (unlikely), `interest` (eventually), `level` (eventually). Can that be the case?

Comment: @Val Those values are always positive..

Comment: @Val But this problem happens after a while.. the first couple of hours I can do queries and get results, lateron I don't receive results naymore, in the mean time i didnt change anything so I find this very weird..

Comment: Since `skill.MinYears` is an input parameter (by users?) is it possible that someone enters a negative value?

Comment: @Val We have thought about that and It shouldn't be that case. The only problem is that I don't know how to see the data in elasticsearch, so I can't tell you for sure, but if that was the case, It should never give me results right? When I index an item with a date, I get the results i nthe frontend, only maybe 5 hours or a day later I cannot get the results.. I have a feeling that elasticsearch is doing things by itself.. is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know how to see the data in elasticsearch"? A good way to debug this is to print out the query before sending it out. Once you have it, we can debug it more easily

Comment: @Val I use Kibana at this moment. And the years of experiences is never below the 0. So the data on ElasticSearch seems fine..

Comment: Still, it would be nice to see the generated query before it gets out.

Comment: @Val I have been trying to get the generated query in raw format, but I haven't succeeded in that.. how am I supposed to get that long value? But you could be right about the yearsOfExperience being a negative value... So I tried to reproduce that by setting the start date 1 year later than the end date, so the score becomes a minus value but I still get results.. while I am expecting not to get a result, so the negative scroes can't be the cause right?

Comment: Can you try this? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-mode.html (i.e. `EnableDebugMode`)

Comment: @Val I added the code to the project and included the debug results in this post. But at this moment it works, after maybe 1 day or something I don't get any results anymore, than I have to reindex. And as you can see, the years experience is -2023, I did that on purpose to see if I could break/reproduce the problem, but I successfully get results. And the -2023 is only used when I select a checkbox on the frontend, but when the app doesn't show the resumes anymore at that moment I didn't even check the checkbox.. so It shouldn't use that anyway..

Comment: @Val Is it possible that ElasticSearch just throws away the current index? Or can there be things broken for me not to get results after a day or 2? Because the negative score seems to not break the application right now.. Maybe it's "All shards failed for phase query elasticsearch" that causes the problem? Thank you very much for your help btw!

Comment: Doesn't the debug information include the query? I'm more interested into the query than the response

Comment: @Val It doesn't seem to include the request information, only the response. The line I included in this post is everything that I get.

Comment: See this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-on-request-completed.html it's in `apiCallDetails.RequestBodyInBytes`

Comment: @Val This: string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
gives me "{}", only 2 bytes. And this: {http://elastic:9200/resumes/_search?typed_keys=true} is the URI.

Comment: @Val I added more important logs. I think ElasticSearch cleans/removes me indexes?

Comment: What makes you think that ES deletes your `resumes` index? What you see in the log `TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction` is ML related and has probably not much to do with your index, or am I mistaken?